# Is there a way to only get the title bar height in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get only the title bar height, but so far I couldn't find an attribute in window which provides this. I want to retrieve this height because when I set the window size, it expects a value including the size of the title bar.

window.getHeight() returns the height of the window including the title bar's height, but I don't know how to retrieve the title bar height from this.

Is there maybe another way of getting the title bar's height?

Comment: Instead of setting the window size, set the Scene size.  Then you won’t have to worry about the title bar height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the height of the title bar using

```
titleHeight = window.getHeight() - scene.getHeight();
```

`window.getHeight()` gives you the full height of the windows, comprised of title bar and content, and `scene.getHeight()` is just the content. You may have to adjust for any borders you set, according to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#getHeight--).